# Iphone, calculating area within an image

Tags: iphone, uiimage, area

Starting a new app and before i get to it would like to know your thoughts... What's the best way to go about calculating image areas.... lets say i have a square 100 X 100 pixels and it has another square on top of it (10 by 10). how would i go about finding the area showing of the 100x100 square? what if there's multiple 10x10 squares and they overlap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a 10,000-element bitmap of all zeros, paint all the squares as ones, and count the zero bits when you're done.

The math will be much faster if you use a 128x128 square, which can be represented by 128 pairs of 64-bit unsigned integers on a 64-bit architecture, or groups of four 32-bit unsigned integers on a 32-bit chip.

Comment: hmmm. i like the idea of using individual pixels. Is there a way to tell the color of each pixel in objective c? Like if i have my original square 100 x 100 and its all black, then i over lay some red 10x10 squares, can i see how many pixels of that 10 000's are red? or do i have to go about this programmaticly?

Comment: If you're only using one color, then it doesn't really matter what the color is; it's the same problem. If you're using more than one color, and you want to know how much of each color there is, after you finish painting, then the simplest solution is to store color values as bytes or RGB-triplets.

Comment: Is it similar to the code found here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357902/reading-and-editing-pixels-of-image-on-iphone